# How to have superview fit to largest intrinsic size subview with autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder

I have a column of multiple dynamic subviews with intrinsic sizes (images, labels, etc). How can I have the superview fit the subviews in autolayout.

If the subviews were not dynamic, I would just constrain the largest subview's leading/trailing edge to the superview. Like so

[image]

I thought I'd be able to align to the leading edge and then have the trailing constraints be `>= 8`, the logic being "The trailing edge can be greater than 8 if the subview is too narrow, but if the subview is wide expand the superview so there's at least a trailing edge of 8." But IB does not like that

**Caveats:**

- Can't use stack view
- subviews have dynamic widths. So in the example any row could be the widest.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's how I got it working. Not sure if this is the best way.

1. Set all the trailing constraints to `>=`
2. Set a width on the superview
3. create an outlet for the superview width constraint
4. In your ViewController, override viewDidLayoutSubviews()

   1. Calculate the largest width out of all your subviews
   2. add your margins to that width
   3. set the superview width constant to the max that was calculated

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps,

1. Add a view (say view A) to the main view.
2. Add all three labels (say label 1, label 2, label 3)to the view A as sub views.
3. Pin View A to its super view to all four sides. Change constraints at the top,bottom,left and right as greater than equal to (>=)10 where priority is set as required(because to avoid view A extending out of the screen if contents extend).
4. Add constraints to label 1, that is pin it to top,right and left of View A by constant is equal to 0. And pin bottom of label 1 to label 2 top is equal to 10 where constraint priority is set as required.
5. Follow same steps to label 2 as well.
6. Follow same steps to label 3. i.e, pin it to bottom of label 2 and right, left of view A. Pin it to bottom of view A, where bottom constraint should be equal 0 where priority is set as low.

You can change constraints values based on your requirements. It will work.
You can change the compression resistance priority to low whosoever label can shrink.

**UPDATE:For the below mentioned git link**

For ViewA add following constraints,

- ViewA center X and Y to SuperView center X and Y (=0 @1000)
- ViewA leading and SuperView leading (>=10 @1000)
- ViewA trailing and SupreView trailing (>=10 @1000)
- ViewA Top and SuperView Top (>=10 @1000)
- ViewA Bottom and Bottom trailing (>=10 @1000)
- Image1 to superview Leading,top (=0 @1000)
- Image1 to superview trailing (>=0 @1000)
- Image1 to Image2 Bottom (=10 @1000)
- Image2 to superview Leading (=0 @1000)
- Image2 to superview trailing (>=0 @1000)
- Image2 to Image3 Bottom (=10 @1000)
- Image3 to superview Leading (=0 @1000)
- Image3 to superview trailing (>=0 @1000)
- Image3 to superView Bottom (=0 @999)

Then select the ViewA and set update frames, there will be still red mark shown indicating Constraints are missing. Still you can add the missing Constraint what xcode suggests but set it to *remove at build time*. Update the frames and run. Hope it works as per your requirement.

Comment: What priority are the constraints from label1/2/3 to viewA? You said label3 to viewA bottom constraint is `low` priority, but what about label1 top, leading, trailing to viewA? label2 leading trailing to viewA, and label3 leading trailing to viewA. Also why is the bottom constraint from label3 to viewA set to low?

I played around with some of the stuff and it was sort of working if I put content hugging really high, but IB complained about the constraints the entire time. I put what I did here https://github.com/iwllyu/TestAutoLayout. That is for xcode 7.3 though

Comment: Label 3 bottom and View A bottom vertical spacing constraint is set to zero and it is of low priority . Rest all constraints are required. Hope I'm clear.

Comment: I tried it and xcode complains about the constraints

Comment: I have checked your code. View controller scene nib constraints are not as per I have mentioned above. I never mentioned width constraint which I can see for the container of labels. And in next scene with images in container. Please add image for image view and check. It needs size. As there is no image it cant decide its intrinsic size.

Comment: You can use >= for trailing constraints for all images else image might stretch.

Comment: Sorry if the project was unclear. the "next scene" was only scene that should have been in the project. I've cleaned up the project. I added 3 images and xcode complains that viewA needs constraints for X position or width. Even though the storyboard complains, the project still runs. When image1/3 are larger, viewA expands as expected, but when image2 becomes smaller viewA does not shrink. I think this is related to the intrinsic size set from the storyboard (if i set image2 to 150x20 initially then everything works great, but not a solution for arbitrary dynamic images)

Comment: I have tried to fix the issue, I'm not sure, its just a try. Let me know your thoughts. I will update above answer.